# Confusion building REST application with proper login in exist-db

Tags: jquery, xquery, exist-db

I am a fairy new user of exist-db was working on building out a content management system. Most all of the components work, but I am having problems figuring out one thing even after reading and reviewing all the documentation.

As a web application, I have many xqueries stored in the DB. Most of these are called via jQuery through AJAX requests.

Now, I am trying to implement a "pretty" login screen. By "pretty" I mean not the standard one that appears when hitting a protected resource in the DB. To me, protection meant locking down all my XQueries so only specific Users or Groups can run them.

For instance, if I hit http://mydburl/tm.xq where tm.xq is locked to a specifc group of users, i get the "default/ugly" login screen like this:

[image]

If I login as one of those users, all is well from then on. And by "well" I mean that there are many other things loaded into the screen -- like collection listings, even a script showing the current user. These are all done via jQuery through an AJAX request to the db. They all execute and they use the credentials of the user I logged in as.

Now, I wanted to attempt to implement a "pretty" screen. I reviewed all the samples and used something like this:

```
    xquery version "3.0";
    import module namespace ls='http://www.xportability.com/ls' at 'listing.xqm';
    declare namespace admin = "http://exist-db.org/xquery/admin-interface";
    declare option exist:serialize "method=xhtml media-type=text/html indent=yes";
    declare function admin:display-login-form() as element() {
     <form action="{session:encode-url(request:get-uri())}" method="post">
        <div
            class="form-group">
            <label
                for="user">Username</label>
            <input
                type="text"
                class="form-control"
                id="user"
                name="user"
                placeholder="Enter username"/>
        </div>
        <div
            class="form-group">
            <label
                for="pass">Password</label>
            <input
                type="password"
                class="form-control"
                id="pass"
                name="pass"
                placeholder="Password"/>
        </div>
        <div
            class="form-group">
            <button id="app_login" type="Submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Login</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    };
    let $isLoggedIn :=  if(xmldb:get-current-user() eq "guest")then
    (
        (: is this a login attempt? :)
        if(request:get-parameter("user", ()) and not(empty(request:get-parameter("pass", ()))))then
        (
            if(request:get-parameter("user", ()) eq "guest")then
            (
                false()
            )
            else
            (
                xmldb:login( $collection, request:get-parameter("user", ()), request:get-parameter("pass", () ), true() )
            )
        )
        else
        (
            false()
        )
    )
    else
    (
        (: if we are already logged in, are we logging out - i.e. set permissions back to guest :)
        if(request:get-parameter("logout",()))then
        (
            let $null  := xmldb:login($collection, "guest", "guest") 
            let $inval := session:invalidate()
            return false()
        )
        else
        (
            true()
        )
    )
    return (

            if($isLoggedIn)then
                (
--- load out the page here ---
```

Now, I set the permissions on that page for "other" to read and execute. It works beautifully and I get a nice login screen. I login in and I am that user in that group. But the page that loads with the "load out the page here" has calls via jQuery Ajax to XQueries in the database (and those XQueries have specific user/group permissions) and the "other" permissions are not on, the instant I execute one it displays the ugly login screen to me. It never does this if I do not use my login and use the "default/ugly" login.

I am lost as to how to make a jQuery Ajax request carry the credentials that I assume are there because they persist when I use the ugly/default login. And I know this is the issue, because if I set r and x permission to all, they execute without a login but I am not even clear under what user.

Is there a better, simple example that I am not finding that shows both:

1) XQueries that are not open permission for everyone to execute

2) Those XQueries are called from XMLHttp/jQuery AJAX as the user.

A sample jQuery might be:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'get-user-info.xq',
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "xml",
    complete: function (Response) {
        user_info = $.parseXML(Response.responseText);
        user_name = $(user_info).find('username').text();
        user_territory = $($(user_info).find('group')[0]).text();
        territory = user_territory.replace('_Territory','');
}});
```

When that is executed in code via button click or action from the current logged in session, it asks to login again with the default ugly login. Now, if I set the permisssions to r-x for all users, then it executes and shows me the current user is actually who I logged in as. But to me, that seems wrong to set permissions to r-x for other or is that incorrect thinking?

Or as a restatement of this question -- is there anyway to get the same behavior of the "ugly" login screen, which completely persists, as a different screen?

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly, you have created a nice login screen, but you also want to make some AJAX requests after authenticating that use the same username/password?

If so, the server needs to be able to associate those additional AJAX requests with the user (that you logged in as), you could either have your requests reuse the session id from the login or you could re-authenticate on each request.

Comment: Exactly., I would have thought that a AJAX request from inside the same domain when a session was set would not require re-authentication. Then I tried various ways to send the session id obtained from login in the AJAX url, nothing worked. I have worked around it through re-authentication but it seems ... just wrong. What I was hoping to see was some example of ... grab the session id here ... then pass it in the AJAX request here.

Comment: Yes the session should be picked up correctly and used for the AJAX requests. Without seeing your exact code and tracing the HTTP traffic it is very hard to diagnose why this is not happening for you; It seems to work in other eXist webapps.

Comment: If this gives you a clue ... I hit that page above login as a particular user *and* the returned page on login loads that XQuery above (which gets the current user). If I remove permissions for "other" (no "r" or "x"), if asked for re-authentication. If I add other permissions for "r" and "x", it runs fine and shows that I am the current user I logged in as. So, that leads me to believe that the credentials are only used in running the XQuery, not when accessing it.